# correct way to iterate through only a certain part of an array?

Tags: python, indexing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/yaahy/PycharmProjects/Testing/testing1.py", line 45, in 
<module>
    clicktheshit()
  File "C:/Users/yaahy/PycharmProjects/Testing/testing1.py", line 41, in 
clicktheshit
    pyautogui.click(chords[0], chords[1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

since my script runs slow searching through every pixel, I want to speed it up by cutting out some of the useless pixels it looks over (the ones not in the gameregion) but using

```
pxlss = pxls[60:400]
```

doesn't work, I don't know the problem because it works without attempting to cut out useless stuff, it's just slow

```
import pyautogui
import time
from PIL import Image
import mss
import mss.tools
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import colorsys

time.sleep(2)

def shootfunc(xc, yc):
    pyautogui.click(xc, yc)

gameregion = [71, 378, 328, 530]

def findpixels(pxls):
    pxlss = pxls[60:400]
    for row, pxl in enumerate(pxlss):
        for col, pxll in enumerate(pxl):
            if col >= 536 and col <= 808 and row <= 515 and row >= 371 and pxll == (102, 102, 102):
                foundpxl = pxll
                print(str(col) + " , " + str(row))
                return [col, row]
                break


def clicktheshit():
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        region = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
        imgg = sct.grab(region)
        pxls = imgg.pixels
        chords = findpixels(pxls)
        pyautogui.click(chords[0], chords[1])

xx = 0
while xx <= 3000:
        clicktheshit()
        xx = xx + 1
        time.sleep(.01)
        clicktheshit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the error message and traceback should give you the first hint:

```
File "C:/Users/yaahy/PycharmProjects/Testing/testing1.py", line 41, in clicktheshit
pyautogui.click(chords[0], chords[1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This means that in this exact line, `chords` is the `None` object - which of course cannot be indexed - instead of the `[col, row]` list you expect.

Now why do you get this `None` instead of the expected list is quite simple: your `findpixels` function only returns this list if it actually finds a match - else, the function ends up without an explicit `return` statement, so it implicitely returns `None`.

IOW, you're problem has nothing to do with the "correct way to iterate through only a certain part of an array"... and a lot to do with not knowing how to debug a program.